# Create database query, change the value depending on the value of another cell

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, case

I have table 'table_bla'

[image]
<sub>(source: [gaskoncev.net](http://gaskoncev.net/assets/table.png))</sub>

Plese help me to creat mysql query.

Description:

- Select obj_id first non-zero value from float_val, from field_id 208,209,210
- If this value >1000 and <2000, then
  update rev_val to 1, this obj_id, where field_id=402
- If this value >2000 and <5000, then
  update rev_val to 2, this obj_id, where field_id=402
- If this value >5000 and <10000, then
  update this rev_val to 3, this obj_id, where field_id=402
- If this value >10000 and <20000, then
  update rev_val to 4, this obj_id, where field_id=402
- ..
- other: 5

Thank you!

Comment: looks like homework to me

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT obj_id, MIN(float_val) AS f
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE field_id in (208, 209, 210)
      GROUP BY obj_id) t2
ON t1.obj_id = t2.obj_id
SET rel_val = CASE WHEN f BETWEEN 1001 and 1999 THEN 1
                   WHEN f BETWEEN 2001 AND 4999 THEN 2
                   WHEN f BETWEEN 5001 AND 9999 THEN 3
                   WHEN f BETWEEN 10001 AND 19999 THEN 4
                   ELSE 5
              END
WHERE t1.field_id = 402
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_bla AS t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT obj_id, float_val AS `value`
            FROM table_bla
            WHERE field_id IN (208,209,210) AND float_val IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY obj_id) AS A ON t.obj_id = A.obj_id
SET rev_val = (CASE WHEN `value` BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 THEN 1 
                    WHEN `value` BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000 THEN 2
                    WHEN `value` BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000 THEN 3
                    WHEN `value` BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN 4
                    ELSE 5
               END)
WHERE field_id = 402;
```

Comment: Where's the `UPDATE` part of the query, to update `rel_val` in the related row?